# Views not responding when forcing wrong orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

I am having an issue where controls are simply not responding on a certain part of the view/window. In my case this is the bottom part.

What I am doing is presenting a new window which has a portrait oriented root view controller. This all seems to work just fine if the application supports a portrait orientation. But when the application is landscape-only the bottom part of the window is not responsive.

(Before you start commenting I should lock the view controller orientation and allow all application orientations let me just tell you that it is a framework and i do not have the access to the application orientations. And yes, it IS a requirement to show in portrait)

So naturally I tried a quick trick by overriding the window hit test but the result was surprisingly already correct. The call to supper will already return the correct view, in the example below it will actually return the button itself that was pressed but the target method does not trigger. So there must be something else that is breaking the pipeline.

Example controller (you can copy it and simply call a static method `showOverlay`):

```
class OverlayViewController: UIViewController {

    class MyWindow: UIWindow {
        override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
            let toReturn: UIView? = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
            print(toReturn)
            return toReturn;
        }
    }

    var myWindow: UIWindow?

    internal static func showOverlay() {
        let window = MyWindow(frame: fullScreenFrame())
        let controller = OverlayViewController()
        window.rootViewController = controller
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        controller.myWindow = window

        var y = 10.0
        while y<2000.0 {
            let view = controller.view
            let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: y, width: 120.0, height: 10.0))
            view.addSubview(btn)
            btn.addTarget(controller, action: "close:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: CGFloat(y/2000.0), alpha: 1.0)

            y += 10.0
        }


    }

    func close(button: UIButton) {
        print("Did press \(button.frame.origin.y)")
    }

    internal static func fullScreenFrame() -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0.0,
            y: 0.0,
            width: (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) ? UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width : UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height),
            height: (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) ? UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height : UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width))
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

Again to reproduce the issue you will need to disable the portrait support in plist.

When you press any of the buttons it will log the button from the hitTest method. But only the top buttons will actually call their target method `close`.

The workaround I can think of is to support all of the orientations and rotate the view manually by applying a transform. But I would prefer to keep the window system if possible simply because it is a pain to cover and keep testing all orientations, handling animations and so forth...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check parent view frame and window frame after rotation. I think it has a wrong size.

Comment: All have correct frame. Also no rotation is performed.